# Powershell change location of dot sourced files

Tags: powershell

I have a Power Shell Module that references a number of PS1 files.

```
. $PSScriptRoot\vs-command.ps1
. $PSScriptRoot\open.ps1
. $PSScriptRoot\git.ps1
. $PSScriptRoot\build.ps1
. $PSScriptRoot\deploy.ps1
. $PSScriptRoot\count.ps1
. $PSScriptRoot\tab.ps1
. $PSScriptRoot\test.ps1
. $PSScriptRoot\nuget.ps1
. $PSScriptRoot\checkforxml.ps1
```

This PSM1 file is held in the location of Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules and currently ties in to the PS1 files referenced above.

The files above perform a number of actions on visual studio projects \ solutions and i now have a requirement for each of the files to be held in their own folder within the solution folder.

I need to find a way of switching the $PSScriptRoot while the same PowerShell window is open.

So.... the requirement is... initial load of these files so i have the basic commands that I would expect... then... when i switch into a Solution Folder held in d:\slns it will detect the root has changed and then pick up the new ps1 files. .

I am very new to powershell so would be very grateful for all help and information.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$PSScriptRoot` is an automatic variable with the path of the folder from which the given PowerShell script was started, i.e. your script is dot-sourcing the other .ps1 files from its own parent folder.

If you need to source files from a different location, you need to replace that variable with the respective path to each file.

I'm still not sure I understand your question, but perhaps something like this will do:

```psh
switch -wildcard ($PSScriptRoot) {
  '*\somefolder\*' {
    . "$PSScriptRoot\A.ps1"
    . "$PSScriptRoot\..\..\C.ps1"
  }
  '*\otherfolder\*' {
    . "$PSScriptRoot\B.ps1"
    . 'C:\some\where\else\D.ps1'
  }
  default {
    . "$PSScriptRoot\A.ps1"
    . "$PSScriptRoot\B.ps1"
  }
}
```

Comment: the plan at the moment is to try and switch powershell environments...  so that no overhand is left in any of the dot sourced information or variables...

Comment: @SimonPrice Sorry, but I have no idea what you're trying to tell me. Please explain (in your question) what your desired result would look like. Examples might help.

Comment: so... i have a number of visual studio solution files, contained in each solution folder there is a powershell modules folder that contains a psm1 and various ps1 files.

When i start powershell it gives me the default moduel and ps1 files as referenced above. 

Not all solutions are going to be created equally and not all psm1 and ps1 files will be the same... 

So... I need a way of switching to the correct psm1 and ps1 files depending on which solution folder \ root I am in thus dropping all current dot sourced information and ensuring there is no overhang of declared variables